# Acurracy really bad for LSTM and cross_val_predict

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to verify the scores of a LSTM prediction for timeseries for a stock market prediction(link to dataset https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/sandp500 , I'm using the AAL stock). The data has this shape:

```
    open    high
0   15.07   15.12
1   14.89   15.01
2   14.45   14.51
3   14.30   14.94
4   14.94   14.96
... ... ...
1254    54.00   54.64
1255    53.49   53.99
1256    51.99   52.39
1257    49.32   51.50
1258    50.91   51.98
1259 rows × 2 columns
```

When using the model.fit and model.predict, I can see that the results are not good, but at least shows that follows the real data.(The image only shows the prediction, so the training was 80% of the dataset)

[image: green is the prediction]

Now, when using the cross_val_predict or cross_val_score, the results are really bad, like 0.30 heading down to 0.003 in the end.
the full code is:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

from tscv import GapKFold
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

sc = MinMaxScaler()
# define parameters
prevision_days = 5
verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 20, 50
size_test = 0.2  #20%

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

# load the dataset file
original_dataset = pd.read_csv('..\\dataset\\all_stocks_5yr.csv')
original_dataset.loc[original_dataset['low'].isnull(),'low'] = original_dataset['close']
original_dataset.loc[original_dataset['open'].isnull(),'open'] = original_dataset['close']
original_dataset.loc[original_dataset['high'].isnull(),'high'] = original_dataset['close']
dataset = original_dataset[original_dataset.Name == 'AAL'].drop(['date', 'volume', 'Name'], axis=1)

dataset = dataset[['open','high']]

#breaking in train/test
test_size = -1*int(prevision_days * round((math.floor(len(dataset)*size_test))/prevision_days))

dataset_scaled = sc.fit_transform(dataset)

#Preparing the data
data = []
target = []
for i in range(prevision_days, len(dataset_scaled)):
    data.append(dataset_scaled[i-prevision_days:i, 0])
    target.append(dataset_scaled[i, 0])
data, target = np.array(data), np.array(target)
data = np.reshape(data, (data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 1))

# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (data.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(units = 50))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(units = 1))

    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
results = cross_val_predict(model, data, target, cv=5)
print(results)
```

the results are:

```
[[0.30032859]
 [0.30032859]
 [0.30032859]
 ...
 [0.00306681]
 [0.00306681]
 [0.00306681]]
```

Any idea what could be causing these results? I already increased the epoch up to 50 and batch_size also to 50, but the results are exact the same, which is also strange.

Many Thanks,
Joao

Comment: Still investigating it, but I found one issue that I was doing: the CV splits in n parts the data, but is in a cycle and not only from the beginning. Using GapWalkFoward made the trick, but I'm still getting really bad results.